# Isn't it convenient to pronounce "-man" in "salesman" and "-men" in "salesmen" differently as you do it in "man [mæn]" and "men [men]"?

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, pronunciation

"Man" and "men" are different in pronunciation:
[man](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/man_1) [m**æ**n]
men [m**e**n]

As are some other word pairs:
[handyman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/handyman) [ˈhændim**æ**n]
handymen [ˈhændim**e**n]
[bogeyman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bogeyman) [ˈbəʊɡim**æ**n]
bogeymen [ˈbəʊɡim**e**n]
[superman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/superman) [ˈsuːpəm**æ**n]
supermen [ˈsuːpəm**e**n]
[a more complete list](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/leninakan):
adman, anchorman, apeman, bagman, batman, bogeyman, cameraman, caveman, chessman, conman, everyman, freedman, frontman, gasman, jazzman, handyman, he-man, hitman, iceman, lawman, legman, linkman, mailman, merman, middleman, motorman, newsman, newspaperman, oilman, packman, ragman, repairman, sandman, schoolman, snowman, spaceman, strawman, strongman, stuntman, superman, swagman, taxman, weatherman, wingman, wireman, yardman

But there are also a lot of other word pairs that are not different in pronunciation, for example:
[salesman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/salesman) [ˈseɪlzm**ə**n]
salesmen [ˈseɪlzm**ə**n]
[chairman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chairman) [ˈtʃeəm**ə**n]
chairmen [ˈtʃeəm**ə**n]
[spokesman](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spokesman) [ˈspəʊksm**ə**n]
spokesmen [ˈspəʊksm**ə**n]

Why?
Isn't it convenient to use different pronunciation everywhere?

Comment: I pronounce salesman/salesmen, chairman/chairmen, spokesman/spokesmen differently, especially if I am dictating.

Comment: Convenient for whom? And what has convenience to do with the unpredictable development of language?

Comment: Better still, avoid all of these gendered terms and use inclusive words instead.

Comment: Isn't the second list, particularly, ignoring accent, context and idiom. Sometimes those terms do sound alike and often, they don't.

Comment: @GregMartin: People still need to be able to pronounce words that they wouldn't use in their own original speech or writing; to quote others, for instance.  If you want to talk about the Arthur Miller play you are going to see, you need to be able to pronounce "salesman".

Comment: "Patrolman" belongs in the second list.

Comment: @MarkFoskey Thanks. I've correct it.

Comment: @GregMartin these terms are not gendered; that would be the etymological fallacy except that the implied etymology isn't even entirely honest. (Originally Old English *mann* was not gendered, but the gendered *wer* fell out of use - the non-gendered sense survives as the modern German indefinite third-person singular pronoun *man*, essentially equivalent to the English use of *one* as a pronoun). People who claim to feel "excluded" by these terms are either misinformed, misguided or else consciously seeking power via redress for grievances that are entirely illusory.

Comment: Pronounce them differently if you like.  I doubt anyone will bat an eye.  I know a non-native speaker who pronounced 'oven' like Oh-ven for decades without anyone mentioning it.  Anyone who cares about such things has too much time on their hands.

Comment: @ColinFine Your questions don't help, they only clog the commentary section.

Comment: @Loviii, my questions that have had eight upvotes? I still don't know why you are asking about "convenience"

Answer (score 22):

Yes. That would be convenient.

But in English, unstressed vowels are often reduced to /ə/.  So from a pronunciation point of view it is easier to say /ˈseɪlzmən/.

There are plenty of examples in your first list which could also be pronounced with /ə/, and it would be possible to say /ˈseɪlzmen/ if you wanted to emphasise the plural.

Comment: 1) Do you mean it's possible to pronounce "_handym**a**n_ [ˈhændim**ə**n]" and "_handym**e**n_ [ˈhændim**ə**n]"? 2) Do you mean it's possible to pronounce "_salesm**a**n_ [ˈseɪlzm**æ**n]" and "_salesm**e**n_ [ˈseɪlzm**e**n]"? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii I don't think anyone would pronounce "handyman" or "superman" with a schwa. Whether the last syllable is stressed depends on the preceding syllable.

Comment: Yes, I think that is at least in part because "handy man" is also valid.  I'd be happy to hear "gasmən" and "salesmæn"

Comment: @Barmar not all would sound natural with a schwa, but some certainly would (e.g. cameraman, repairman, snowman, stuntman). But I'm not sure it can simply be reduced to stress patterns, and [ˈhændimən] is sometimes heard in some British English (though not my accent)

Comment: @ChrisH Good point. I think British accents tend to make more use of [mən] than American. I kind of liken it to their pronunciation of Ma'm as "mum".

Comment: @Barmar I don't think we pronounce "Ma'am" as "mum". We use our PALM vowel for the former and STRUT for the latter; I think you do sometimes hear TRAP, I don't know if this is an Americanism or what. Quite similar vowels, true, but definitely not the same.

And yeah, I generally agree that it's probably down to English tending to prefer alternating patterns of stress. "Salesman" probably breaks that rule because of its varisyllabic nature - some (especially those with vocalised 'l's) would pronounce it with two syllables (sounding like "sellsman"), others with three.

Comment: @Muzer "ma'am" as "mum" has existed in some British accents in the past, but of course it's a rare word these days anyway. Then there's "mam" (TRAP vowel) for "mum" (American "mom") in Welsh English.

Comment: There are some dialects of English in which reduced front vowels (e/i) are distinguished from reduced back vowels (a/o/u).  The conventional minimal pair is "roses" versus "Rosa's".

Comment: Standard complaint: all of this is approximation and modeling anyway. Not only does /ə/ not have to be [ə] (it could for example be [ʌ]), but [ə] and [ʌ] don't mean specific exact sound frequency spectra, any more than "green" and "red" mean specific exact *light* frequency spectra. (@dan04 my speech has this distinction, although I would say it's not particularly strong.) Related cross-site: [American English : are \[ə\] and \[ʌ\] different phonemes? \(schwa vs. chevron\)](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19851)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [ə] and [ʌ] _do_ refer to regions of a formant chart. This documented by the IPA. It's just that traditional transcriptions of English don't follow those because they lag behind

Answer (score 16):

The words in your second list are far more common than those in the first. That everyday use is what contributes to the change in pronunciation.

John McWhorter in [*Words on the Move*](https://%5B1%5D:%20https://www.google.com/books/edition/Words_on_the_Move/vKqTCwAAQBAJ?hl=en) gives us the explanation behind this phenomenon :

> ﻿**Often if a word is part of the unaccented part of [a] compound, then it starts being pronounced more fuzzily, and drifts ever farther beyond what we would think of as a word in any sense at all.**
>
> Take *policeman, fireman, clergyman, postman, and gentleman*: one does not pronounce the *-man* part the way one would pronounce *man* by itself. Rather, you say something like "mun," a sludgy "whatever" kind of pronunciation. That has happened over the years, as the words have undergone
> what you could call enunciational wear. Originally, the *-man* in these words was pronounced fully, but now, if someone had no idea how English was written and heard words like *policeman* and *fireman*, they might not even associate the little *-mun* with the word *man* at all. One way we know that this pronunciation of *-man* develops gradually over time is that if you start all over again and make up a new word with *-man* on the end, you will usually pronounce the -man fully. *Anchorman* and *caveman* are newish concepts; yes, cavemen themselves date pretty far back, but what taught us that they existed was paleontology, which does not. Therefore those two words are pronounced with "man" rather than "mun."
>
> ---
>
> [pages 188-9]

So that 'sludgy' pronunciation is what you're hearing in words like *salesman*/*salesmen* being said the same.
From the hearer's perspective, having that distinction is useful. From the speaker's perspective, enunciating that distinction is tedious.

Answer (score 9):

Where I'm from, all 3 of your examples *are* pronounced differently.

Comment: Do you pronounce "_salesm**a**n_ [ˈseɪlzm**æ**n]" and "_salesm**e**n_ [ˈseɪlzm**e**n]"? Thanks.

Comment: The difference is subtle for me, but it's definitely there. The singular gets contracted and comes closer to being -mun or -mn rather than "man" with a broad a, but it's definitely not -men with an eh.

Comment: @keshlam Agree 100%!  The "men" in salesmen is like "mend". "salesman" cannot be pronounced that way; the vowel cannot stray that far from centre. And "salesmen" cannot be shortened to "salesmn" except in very rapid speech. "salesman" gets shortened even in slow speech.

Comment: How many colors can you dye a lect?

Comment: Where do you come from? Kentucky, US? Brisbane, Australia? Birmingham, UK? Toronto? Yes, it's Indiana I took a peek at your profile. Might be a good idea to actually say so in the "answer".

Comment: I could go either way.  Kind of depends on how fast I am talking and whom I am talking to.

Answer (score 0):

A key difference between your two lists is their syllable counts.

There are few (if any) words with secondary stress on a syllable adjacent to the primary stress syllable.

Secondary stress can be enough to avoid collapsing a short vowel to a schwa, especially when that's the only point of difference between a related pair of words.

Counting candidates for stress isn't exact, as different dialects and even individuals will treat diphthongs, vowel length, and consonant clustering slightly differently. Dialects also differ in *which* vowels are candidates for schwa collapse (some have only one, which makes schwa a functional allophone for that vowel).

Another word pair for your second list: *woman* vs *women*.